# I want to compare value of each column using react-table

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, react-table

I am new to react.

I made table using react-table module. following the example page. But i got new problem

I made 2rows of table. and what i want to make is to compare the value of each column then make different background color.

But i could not find the way to control the each cell. (what i made is below)

[image]

then my table component is below.

```
import { useTable } from "react-table"

const TableContainer = ({ columns, data }) => {
  const {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    rows,
    prepareRow,
  } = useTable({
    columns,
    data,
  })
  return (<table {...getTableProps()} style={{ border: 'solid 1px blue' }}>
  <thead>
    {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
      <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
        {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
          <th
            {...column.getHeaderProps()}
            style={{
              borderBottom: 'solid 3px red',
              background: 'aliceblue',
              color: 'black',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize:'10px',
            }}
          >
            {column.render('Header')}
          </th>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ))}
  </thead>
  
  <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
       
    {rows.map(row => {  
      prepareRow(row)
      return (
        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
          {row.cells.map(cell => { 
            
            return (
              <td
                {...cell.getCellProps()}
                style={{
                  padding: '10px',
                  border: 'solid 1px gray',
                  background: 'papayawhip',
                  fontSize : '10px',
                }}
              >
                {cell.render('Cell')}
              </td>
            )
          })}
        </tr>
      )
    })}
  </tbody>
</table>)}

export default TableContainer
```

i could compare value of each column like this way.

```
{rows[0].values["폴산"] !== rows[1].values["폴산"]? console.log("diffenent") : console.log("same") }
```

but i can not find the way to access the each cell styling

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the index of the cell while you map. As I remember cells[index] should have something like a value attribute in it

```
{rows[0].cells[index].value!==rows[1].cells[index].value}
```

like this

```
row.cells.map((cell, index) => {
 style={{
                  padding: '10px',
                  border: {rows[0].cells[index].value!==rows[1].cells[index].value 
? '1px solid red' : '1px solid blue'},
                  background: 'papayawhip',
                  fontSize : '10px',
                }}


}
```